# how to know if a profile is connected to a wireless ntework with wlanapi

Tags: wlanapi

i can't found the function in wlan api to know if a profile is connected or not to a network.

WlanGetAvailableNetworkList gives only networks with profile associated.

Thansk for your help.

Answer (score 0):

answer :
use WlanRegisterNotification

and check NotificationCode == wlan_notification_acm_connection_complete with 
wlanReasonCode == WLAN_REASON_CODE_SUCCESS in structure WLAN_CONNECTION_NOTIFICATION_DATA